# Convex mesh collider shape

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use a flat 3d circle in my game. I need circle collider in 3D, but it doesn't exist in unity. I created circle with 500 vertices and added mesh collider. If I don't check convex it looks correct. With convex it changes to box collider. How can I make a circle collider?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Cylinder in a 3D modeling program like Blender with a very small height.

[image]

Export it as a FBX to Unity and then apply a mesh collider to it, next hide the object by removing the Mesh Renderer making it invisible leaving only the collider.

[image]

Comment: Correct solution but wouldn't, a simple small height cylinder collider would do the same, without the need of modelling?

Comment: @Menyus Not for a flat circle no, The in-built cylinder collider has rounded hemisphere ends.

Comment: yeah you are right i was ona  train and thought unity has a cylinder collider, but it actually only has capsule, sphere and box.